# Please to compare two variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data in mysql table but it should not be inserted before..

I have try comparing variable it always fails.

```
<?PHP
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sunil_electronics";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT p_id FROM inquirycart WHERE p_id='$pid'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// output data of each row
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$id = $row['p_id'];

if ($id == $pid) {
    header('Location: ' . $url . '&key1=' . $key . '&info=info');
} else {
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO inquirycart (p_id,p_name, p_image)
        SELECT p_id, p_name, p_image FROM $key
        WHERE p_id = '$pid'";
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

    header('Location: ' . $url . '&key1=' . $key . '&succ=succ');
}
?>
```

Comment: Please note that `$pid` isn't defined in your code.

Comment: There is many sql injection vulnerabilities on your code, don't forget to fix them.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning but i am using $key=$_GET['key']; , $url=$_GET['url']; , $pid=$_GET['id'];

Comment: Did you tried to dump $id variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `p_id` is not used before, the query won't return any rows. `$result->fetch_assoc()` will return `NULL`, and `$row['p_id']` will fail.

You can just check the number of rows returned.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header('Location: ' . $url . '&key1=' . $key . '&info=info');
} else {
    ...
}
```